# Haven't been able to boot this drive in about a week. Winload.efi. "Weird" partition table?

Tags: windows-10, boot, partitioning, ssd, uefi

### How the error came to be

---

1. I opened **testdisk** out of curiosity and started **analyzing my system drive**.
   It was painfully slow so I eventually **killed** the process, and nothing spectacular happened it killedwindows was functioning normally.
2. I opened disk management to check partitions on another drive, that wasn't showing so I clicked "refresh" in disk management and the PC immediately froze, hasn't booted since. There also seems to be a "*random*" 16MB unallocated partition between the EFI and the main partition.
   [Partition Table In Disk Management](https://i.stack.imgur.com/w5QQe.png)
3. I've attempted repair using installation media, then diskpart, and bootrec /rebuildbcd, I've gotten nowhere the same thing every time. I've also checked secure boot settings, boot order, and CSM and pretty much everything else I could think of.
4. After a week of the PC being unbootable I decided to buy another SSD just to install fresh copy of windows so I could get some use out of the PC. But I really would love to get that drive to boot!

---

I'm asking for this help because I don't have a full understanding of filesystems and partitions. The data on this drive is still there but I REALLY need it to boot! I shouldn't have been messing around with them in the first place...

```
This post is my last resort... D:
```

Thanks in advance guys!

Comment: You haven't actually described symptoms of the problem. When you say _"hasn't booted since"_, what does that mean exactly? Please use the [Edit] button. That 16 MB unallocated space is normal, Windows leaves it unprovisioned by default in case it needs to put something at the beginning of the next partition.

Comment: windload.efi error on bootup. That's the only symptom the PC doesn't boot and throws a winload.efi 0x0000025 error. I might have the number of 0s wrong.

Comment: It's highly unlikely that testdisk destroyed the disk. It's more likely that the large amount of I/O that it generated caused a weak disk to fail. Try to get the SMART data of the disk to check its state.